# Ungroup a node group while keeping parameters?

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes

I have created a nodegroup but now I want to ungroup it but when I did I found that all my parameters have gone and I have to put it again,
so is there is any way I can ungroup a nodegroup while keeping the parameters?

**some more explination:**

what I have here is some node groups in the compositor which have some inputs connected to values which when ungrouping it stay connected but the problem is not in the connected values . the problem is in the value which is not connected to anything like this value 
[image]

and when I ungroup the the node group this values return to its default value that I set when I made the node group,notice the image below the red one is the sockets connected which is fine and no problem in that but the values which was 155 become 0.5 which is the default value
[image]

**so what I need now is to have the value that I set before ungrouping to be the same after ungrouping**

Comment: It looks like Linegenerator Node is itself is a group, can't you supply the values not supposed to be reset by a value node as you did in other places?

Comment: I find that this is the best solution,thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can't solve this problem inside the nodeGroup itself, but you can add a value Node (for gray input factor values, RGB/vector for yellow/blue) outside of your group, plug it (from outside) to the factor input of your group and use it for tweaking and the when you ungroup, it'll keep it plugged and the value will be the same as before.

inside group
[image: tabbed group]

values lost when ungrouped, default values applied
[image: lost]

values linked from outside
[image: linked]

values saved and linked after ungrouping
[image]

As far as I know, it's not a bug, it's the normal behavior of node groups. Values are stored in the group, not in individual nodes inside the group. So when you ungroup (delete the group) all stored infos are deleted too.

Answer (score 1):

You could keep you externally available inputs by using reroute nodes (*Menu:Add/Layout/Reroute*).

[image]

Drawback is that neither parameter names nor data type is propagated (parameters are labeled as 'Input')

[image]

Nodes after ungroup:

[image]

Comment: I feel like I'm still missing something - it just _works_ when I ungroup something.

Comment: @someonewithpc Do you still have the input sockets assigned to the groups input after ungrouping?

Comment: Yes, everything is still connected

Comment: @someonewithpc then you should add another illustrated answer. I'm curious how this works, just used Ctrl-G and Alt-G. In my case there is no longer a reference of which input nodes were wired to the group node.

Comment: Are you using Blender 2.73a?

Comment: @someonewithpc That could make the difference 2.73 from 2014-12-23

Comment: I just tested, and 2.73 RC does the same as 2.73a...

Comment: I have edited the question for more explanation.

Comment: @OmarAhmad you could add value nodes to th

Answer (score 0):

I still feel like I'm missing something, because, when I ungroup a set of nodes, the connections are still fine; I'm using the latest release, 2.73a, so it might have been a fixed bug; however, a quick search trough the recently fixed bugs, related to ungrouping, seems to only reveleal ["Linked nodetree group looses connections when made local and ungrouped"](https://developer.blender.org/T21640) as relevant.

[image]

Comment: I think he has a huge group and want to keep a few important parameters when editing the group. You wired the diffuse to a RGB before grouping, this seems to be maintained after ungrouping. Let's wait for the OPs response.

Comment: Do you mean _without __anything___ connected?

Comment: I might be wrong but this is how I interpreted the question.

Comment: @stacker That makes more sense, I guess...

Comment: I have edited the question for more explanation.